# How to find index of a number in a given string

Tags: c#, string, indexing

I need to find position of string in a given string.
The string changes every time because it is coming from service.
The format like below:

> Ali||Atay||3||5||izmir
>
> Furkan||Altun||1||2||istanbul

How to get the position of `1` or `3` ?
It is after 4 ( | symbol )

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and we'll be able to help you, with your code. We don't make the code for you.

Comment: I need to find only a string method. It is only part of the code.

Comment: You should really explain your requirement better **and** show what you have tried. I guess the actual requirement is to determine the number which is the third field in each line. You could use `String.Split`

Comment: "It is after 4 ( | symbol )" does it mean that you need to count the amount of the `|` symbols and after the forth you will find the number that you are looking for?

Comment: "The string changes every time" amazingly unclear. What exactly can change in this string? everything? parts of it? if so which parts? how does it change? only the positions? ....

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample:

```
  // Find the index of 1.
  Console.WriteLine(s1.IndexOf("1"));
  // Find the index of 2.
  Console.WriteLine(s2.IndexOf("2"));
```

Comment: "How to get pozition of 1 or 3" and "The string changes every time". The requirement is extremely vague. Any answer attempt will inevitably be not enough. In your case: How will this code find the index of `3` ?

Comment: I do agree but this is the closest we all can get with this information.

Answer (score 0):

```
string input="Furkan||Altun||1||2||istanbul";
int index=input.IndexOf("1");
```

index now contains the position of the character 1.

Comment: "How to get pozition of 1 or 3" and "The string changes every time". The requirement is extremely vague. Any answer attempt will inevitably be not enough. In your case: How will this code find the index of `3` ?

Comment: I'd probably change it to `int index=input.IndexOf("3");`. Whilst it might be vague, bear in mind you are answering a beginner's question, and therefore, hopefully, with a couple of examples, the OP will be able to extrapolate a solution that works for them, and then post their solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.IndexOf(givenString.Split('|'), "1");
```

Comment: "How to get pozition of 1 or 3" and "The string changes every time". The requirement is extremely vague. Any answer attempt will inevitably be not enough. In your case: How will this code find the index of `3` ?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you want to process `string`: it seems that you actually deal with an **object** serialized as a *csv* (with `|` separator)

```
  public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(string firstName, string secondName, 
                   int firstValue, int secondValue, 
                   string from) {
      //TODO: Validate arguments here: do you accept null? negative values? etc.
      FirstName = firstName; 
      SecondName = secondName;
      FirstValue = firstValue;
      SecondValue = secondValue;
      From = from; 
    }

    public static MyClass Parse(string csvLine) {
      if (null == csvLine)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("csvLine"); 

      string[] items = csvLine.Split('|');

      try {
        return new MyClass(items[0], items[2],
                           int.Parse(items[4]),int.Parse(items[6]),
                           items[8]);
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        throw new FormatError("Incorrect CSV format", e); 
      }
    }

    public string ToCsv() {
      return string.Join("|", 
        FirstName, "", SecondName, "", FirstValue, "", SecondValue, "", From);
    };

    //TODO: Put a better names for the properties
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string SecondName {get; set;}
    public int FirstValue {get; set;}
    public int SecondValue {get; set;}
    public string From {get; set;}  
  }
```

Having this class implemented you can operate with it as simple as

```
  // Given a string
  string source = "Ali||Atay||3||5||izmir";

  // We parse it into specially designed object
  MyClass item = MyClass.Parse(source);

  // Work with Names, Values as we please
  if (item.FirstValue == 3)
    item.FirstValue = 55;

  // If we want a csv representation we can easily obtain it
  string result = item.ToCsv();
```